# If $ab=1$ in $A/I$ then there is $a'b' =1$ in $A/I^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity and $I\subset A$ be an ideal. If $ab=1$ in $A/I$, then can we find $a',b'\in A/I^2$ such that $a'b' =1$ in $A/I^2$ and $f(a') = a$ and $f(b')=b$ where $f:A/I^2\to A/I$ is the natural quotient map?

Is the above statement true? If so, how can I find such $a',b'$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will seem like an answer that comes out of nowhere, but it took some trial and error and I actually was hoping for hints of a counterexample going in.

Suppose $(a+I)(b+I)=1+I$ in $A/I$. Then $ab-1\in I$. Take $a'=a$, and $b'=b-b(ab-1)$.

Then clearly $f(a'+I^2)=a'+I=a+I$, and $f(b'+I^2)=b'+I=b+I$.

Now $a'b'=ab-ab(ab-1)=-(ab-1)^2+1$. Therefore $(a'+I^2)(b'+I^2)=1+I^2$ in $A/I^2$.

Comment: This proof is valid for noncommutative rings $A$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the answer of @August Liu:

If $a b = 1 - n$, where $n \in I$, then $a b (1+n)= 1-n^2$.
Now take $a'=a$, $b' = b(1+n)$.

We can do this for every morphism of rings with the kernel consisting of nilpotent elements.

Comment: In fact, it is true that if $I \subset \mathrm{Jac}(R)$ is contained in the Jacobson radical, $R^\times \to (R/I)^\times$ is surjective.

Comment: @Balarka Sen: I see.. definitely $1-n$ is invertible... will the inverse be of the form $1-m$, with $m$ in the ideal $I$ again? Not clear to me at the moment

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated. If $a \in R$ such that $\bar{a} \in (R/I)^\times$, then there exists $b$ such that $ab -1 \in I$. $I$ is contained in the Jacobson radical, therefore in any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, so $ab - 1 \in \mathfrak{m}$. This implies $a \notin \mathfrak{m}$, otherwise $1 = (-1)(ab - 1) + a(b) \in \mathfrak{m}$! Blasphemy. So $a$ is not contained in _any_ maximal ideal, which means it is a unit in $R$.

Comment: @Balarka Sen: I guess I was just unclear about the inverse of $(1-n)$, it should have been clear though, mod $I$ the inverse of $1$ is still $1$, silly me.